# Doughts and crosses in windows form application

Tags: c#, forms

can someone tell me why I can't run my program? I'm trying to create doughts and crosses in windows form applications I tried changing the code and stuff but I've tried everything but I think something is wrong with my function at the bottom. By now, I wanted to program to run, generate 9 buttons and when I click on them an "X" or "O" would appear depending whose turn is it.

PS. I haven't added the win condition function yet I wanted to test if the program is working as it should.

Thanks in advance.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Button[] gameButtons = new Button[9]; //array of buttons for markers(X's and O's)
    bool cross = true; //cross is set to true if the next marker is to be a cross


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = "More Complex Version of Noughts and Crosses";
        this.BackColor = Color.BlanchedAlmond;
        this.Width = 400;
        this.Height = 400;

        for (int i = 0; i < gameButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            int index = i;
            this.gameButtons[i] = new Button();
            int x = 50 + (i % 3) * 50;
            int y = 50 + (i / 3) * 50;

            this.gameButtons[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
            this.gameButtons[i].Name = "btn" + (index + 1);
            this.gameButtons[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
            this.gameButtons[i].TabIndex = i;
            //this.gameButtons[i].Text = Convert.ToString(index);
            this.gameButtons[i].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.gameButtons[i].Visible = true;

            gameButtons[i].Click += (sender1, ex) => this.buttonHasBeenPressed(sender,index);
            this.Controls.Add(gameButtons[i]);
        }

    }

            private void buttonHasBeenPressed(object sender,int i)
            {
                if (((Button)sender).Text == "")
                {
                    if (cross == true)
                    {
                        ((Button)sender).Text = "X";
                        gameButtons[i] = 'X';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((Button)sender).Text = "O";
                        gameButtons[i] = 'O';
                    }
                    cross = !cross;
                }
            }
}
```

Edit: The first problem was solved, thanks a lot to everyone :) But now I'm struggling to find the win condition. I've used this code but I'm getting a compiler error that I don't seem to understand how to fix it. This is the code I've made up:

```
private void threeInARow(int a, int b, int c, object sender)
    {
        if (gameButtons[a]==gameButtons[b] && gameButtons[a]==gameButtons[c])
        {
            if (gameButtons[a]='X')
            {
                MessageBox.Show("the winner is crosses");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("the winner is noughts");
            }
        }
```

The error is on my my first if it says "cannot implicitly convert type char to system.windows.forms.button"

Comment: You should be more specific and say what error you're getting or which line of code is failing.

Comment: You don't need *us* to tell you why it won't run. The compiler will tell you exactly what the problem is and on what line. Maybe you should start there.

Comment: line 59 and 64  gameButtons[i]='X'; is failing I get a red line at the x and o respectively

Comment: `if (gameButtons[a]='X')` should be `if (gameButtons[a].Text[0]=='X')`

Comment: And where will the method be placed and with what parameters? Sorry if I ask too much I'm just struggling with that for days.

Comment: Please select Rufus L's answer as accepted. He has made a great deal of effort to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you have some compile errors:

```
// These two lines both throw the error:
// Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
gameButtons[i] = 'X'; 
gameButtons[i] = 'O';
```

This is because you're trying to set a button to a character. This is not necessary, since you've already changed the text of the button, and you can remove these lines.

Next, you get a runtime exception when clicking on a button, on this line:

```
// The following line fails with the error:
// Unable to cast object of type 'WinFormTest.Form1' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'.
if (((Button)sender).Text == "")
```

This is because the `sender` is the `Form1` object, and not the button. The reason for this is that, in your assignment of the event to the button Click, you are passing `sender` instead of `sender1` to the event, and, since the assignment of this event is happening in the `Form.Load` event, `sender` is the `Form1`. So you need to change the assignment to pass `sender1` instead:

```
gameButtons[i].Click += (sender1, ex) => this.buttonHasBeenPressed(sender1, index);
```

---

The next problem you're having (since you've modified the code in the original question) is in the `threeInARow` method here:

```
if (gameButtons[a] = 'X') // Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'Button'
```

The reason for this is that `gameButtons` is an array of `Button` objects, so `gameButtons[a]` represents a `Button`, and you can't assign the character `'X'` to a `Button` (they are two different types). Since you've already assigned a value to the `Text` property of each button (which is of `string` type), you can just use that instead.

Also, you are using a single `=` sign, which is an assignment. You want to do a comparison, which uses a double `==` sign. So, putting these together, you will get:

```
if (gameButtons[a].Text == "X")
```

You have added similar problematic code to your `buttonHasBeenPressed` method, which you should just remove since we can compare the `Text` properties and don't need this additional assignement:

```
gameButtons[i] = 'X'; // Remove these invalid assignments
```

That takes care of the compile error, but you still have another problem in your comparisons with this line:

```
if (gameButtons[a] == gameButtons[b] && . . .
```

This line is asking if the `Button` reference in the array at index `a` is pointing to the exact same object as the `Button` reference in the array at index `b`. This will never be the case because you (correctly) initialized your array with 9 unique buttons.

What you really want to do is compare the `Text` property of each button, like so:

```
if (gameButtons[a].Text == gameButtons[b].Text && . . .
```

Lastly, you have included an `Object` parameter named `sender` to your method that you aren't using, so you might as well remove that (or do something with it in your method).

So, putting this all together you have:

```
private void threeInARow(int a, int b, int c)
{
    if (gameButtons[a].Text == gameButtons[b].Text && gameButtons[a].Text == gameButtons[c].Text)
    {
        if (gameButtons[a].Text == "X")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("the winner is crosses");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("the winner is noughts");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And how about the winning condition? Will it be something like that?

     private void threeInARow (int a, int b, int c)
        {
            if (gameButtons[a] == gameButtons[b] && gameButtons[a] == gameButtons[c])
            {
                if (gameButtons[a] = 'X')
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The winner is crosses");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The winner is noughts");
                }
            }

Comment: No, I just realised that I'm still trying to add a button to a character.

Comment: What I meant by a different question was that you should mark an answer to this one and post a new one. You should not keep asking new questions with the first question. I've answered it this time, but notice now that the answer is getting way too long and complicated. Please mark as answered and start a new question if you have any more!

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering and for explaining, also sorry for that I didn't want to "spam" new questions for a something similar problem. I didn't knew I'm kinda new to coding and to this site but thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Button[] gameButtons = new Button[9]; //array of buttons for markers(X's and O's)
        bool cross = true; //cross is set to true if the next marker is to be a cross
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = "More Complex Version of Noughts and Crosses";
            this.BackColor = Color.BlanchedAlmond;
            this.Width = 400;
            this.Height = 400;

            for (int i = 0; i < gameButtons.Length; i++)
            {
                int index = i;
                this.gameButtons[i] = new Button();
                int x = 50 + (i % 3) * 50;
                int y = 50 + (i / 3) * 50;

                this.gameButtons[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
                this.gameButtons[i].Name = "btn" + (index + 1);
                this.gameButtons[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
                this.gameButtons[i].TabIndex = i;
                //this.gameButtons[i].Text = Convert.ToString(index);
                this.gameButtons[i].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                this.gameButtons[i].Visible = true;

                gameButtons[i].Click +=  new EventHandler(buttonHasBeenPressed);
                this.Controls.Add(gameButtons[i]);
            }

        }
        private void buttonHasBeenPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (((Button)sender).Text == "")
            {
                if (cross == true)
                {
                    ((Button)sender).Text = "X";
                    //gameButtons[i].Text = "X";
                }
                else
                {
                    ((Button)sender).Text = "O";
                    //gameButtons[i].Text = 'O';
                }
                cross = !cross;
            }
        }
    }
}
```